# How to open multiple jquery dialogs in same page

Tags: jquery

I have atleast 20 links in a page and on each link i have to show a popup with different content.Is there any way that i can call only one javascript function and pass it id of div that has to be displayed as popup.My html structure looks like this

```
<div id='1'>    
<a href='#'>Moreinfo</a>
<div id='popup1'>
Content for first link
</div>
</div>

<div id='2'>
<a href='#'>Moreinfo</a>
<div id='popup2'>
Content for first link
</div>
</div>
```

Also if i click other link first one should close.
Please give suitable example in reply.
Thanks

Comment: are popup divs hidden?

Comment: Give them all a `class` and make use of `this`

Comment: This link might help:  http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this

```
<div class="popupHolder">
    <div class="clickToPopup">Click here</div>
    <div class="popup">your popup content</div>
</div>
<div class="popupHolder">
    <div class="clickToPopup">Click here</div>
    <div class="popup">your popup content</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".clickToPopup").click(function(){
             $(".popup").hide();
             $(this).parent("div.popupHolder").children("div.popup").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pKa6P/)***

You could do it like this

```
$("div[id^=popup]").hide();
$("a").click(function(){
 $("div[id^=popup]").hide();
 var id = this.parentNode.id;
 $("#popup"+id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='1' class="div">
<a href='#'>Moreinfo</a>

    <div id='popup1' class="poppup">Content for first link</div>
</div>
<div id='2' class="div">
<a href='#'>Moreinfo</a>

    <div id='popup2' class="poppup">Content for first link</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $('.div').click(function () {
        $('.poppup').hide();
        $(this).children('.poppup').show();
    });
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/yAVDg/3/)